# Static variables in ProgressListener

Tags: java, weblogic, static-variables

I have the following code in my Weblogic portal app:

```
public class RoutesProgressListener implements ProgressListener {

private static long bytesTransferred = 0;
private static long fileSize = -100;
```

In the above class `bytesTransferred` and `fileSize` variables are static. What problems might these variables cause?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, since these variables are static, they are associated with the class, not object. Thus they are shared by definition.

Secondly, what type of listener is this? If it is a `HttpSessionListener`, it is application-scoped. Thus even if you make these variables non-static, they will be shared by all users too.

Comment: Listener is org.apache.commons.fileupload.ProgressListener;

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. My original answer still stands. If you use static variable, they are associated with the class and thus will be shared.

Answer (score 0):

The main problem with this code is that you have defined these variables to be static, which implies two things:

1. Only one instance of `bytesTransferred` and `fileSize` will ever be created in a single JVM.
2. All threads will share these values.

A Java EE container like Weblogic is a multi-threaded environment, so any time you have more than one active connection, you're going to run into problems.

Try changing these to instance (non-static) variables, and instantiate a new ProgressListener for every request.